# How to configure cmake-based project for a build with Qt

Tags: c++, qt, cmake

[here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/cmake-manual.html) is a doc about that, but it doesn't look correct for me ,
so I've copied cmake instructions into my cmakelists.txt and it doesn't work.
it's clear why it doesn't work - because there is no one instruction how to search qt:

I suppose two cases:

- some additional cmake instructions requires to set
- some environment variables should be set

but nothing about that.

the instruction :

```
find_package(Qt5Widgets)
```

refers to extra cmake script from qt kit , isn't it? 
I see the directory with that name (annd contains *.cmake scripts but another names) but there is no the script with this name

these are the only .cmake files with qt in names in cmake 3.6 :

```
cmake-3.6\Modules\DeployQt4.cmake
cmake-3.6\Modules\FindosgQt.cmake
cmake-3.6\Modules\FindQt.cmake
cmake-3.6\Modules\FindQt3.cmake
cmake-3.6\Modules\FindQt4.cmake
cmake-3.6\Modules\Qt4ConfigDependentSettings.cmake
cmake-3.6\Modules\Qt4Macros.cmake
cmake-3.6\Modules\UseQt4.cmake
```

===================

> C:\dev\tools\CLion.RC\bin\cmake\bin\cmake.exe -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug
>   -G "CodeBlocks - MinGW Makefiles" C:\dev\workspace\algolist.v2 CMake Warning at CMakeLists.txt:14 (find_package):   By not providing
>   "FindQt5Widgets.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project   has asked
>   CMake to find a package configuration file provided by   "Qt5Widgets",
>   but CMake did not find one.
>
> Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Qt5Widgets"
>   with   any of the following names:
>
> ```
> Qt5WidgetsConfig.cmake
> qt5widgets-config.cmake
> ```
>
> Add the installation prefix of "Qt5Widgets" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or
>   set   "Qt5Widgets_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above
>   files.  If   "Qt5Widgets" provides a separate development package or
>   SDK, be sure it has   been installed.
>
> CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:20 (target_link_libraries):   Cannot
>   specify link libraries for target "helloworld" which is not built by
>   this project.
>
> -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred! See also "C:/dev/workspace/algolist.v2/cmake-build-debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".

seems it found Qt5Widgets, but absolutely not clear how it does this...
so it looks for cmake files inside Qt5Widgets folder, in Qt kit.
I can add this folder to the path but I don't think this is a valid way,
because there is a lot of subfolders with cmake files

---

Qt5.8 beta, built with MinGW, Win10, cmake 3.6

Comment: ***because there is no one instruction how to search qt*** On windows you need to set `QT_CMAKE_PATH` in cmake-gui to the location of the root of the Qt cmake files when it can't find Qt (which it never does for me bcause I don't install this in Program Files). If you built Qt from source the folder is the `qtbase\lib\cmake` folder.

Comment: `Qt5WidgetsConfig.cmake` is the file that is needed for this `find_package(Qt5Widgets)`

Comment: thank you, but it didn't help me, let me update the question

Comment: ***these are the only .cmake files with qt in names in cmake 3.6*** That is correct. The locations of the .cmake files you need are included in Qt5 and are not part of CMake itself.

Comment: ***but it didn't help me*** You did not seem to open cmake-gui and set the variable that I told you to set. When you do this make sure your source and build folders for your project are correct in cmake-gui.

Comment: you are right - the line in the script :
set(QT_CMAKE_PATH "C:/dev/tools/Qt58.beta/5.8"), is not enough?

Comment: I am not sure `C:/dev/tools/Qt58.beta/5.8` is the correct folder. Although I always build Qt from source. In `qtbase\lib\cmake` there are 46 subfolders each containg .cmake files.

Comment: is the root of Qt kit should be a folder with /bin; /doc; /include; /lib, etc... ?

Comment: For me it is not the root folder containing what you describe. The folder I use has 46 subfolders with most of these subfolders containing .cmake files

Comment: thank you for your patience! because we can't share screenshot here, could you share your root folder subfolders names?

Comment: Qt5, Qt5AxBase, Qt5AxContainer, Qt5AxServer, Qt5Bluetooth, Qt5Concurrent, Qt5Core ...

Comment: This may be a subfolder of the lib folder since that is where it exists when I build from source.

Comment: sorry, my inattention... I missed root of qt "cmake" folder. yes, I see what you are talking about. let me test

Comment: unfortunatelly it didn't solve the problem too, the same output...

Comment: looks like a magic of qtcreator - this works there , but doesn't from commandline or another IDEs

Comment: I do this from the command line for building Visual Studio projects. No idea why it does not work for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/variable/CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH.html).

For example:

```
cmake.exe -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH="C:/path/to/Qt/5.X/compiler/lib/cmake"
```

Comment: If you are using CLion, click `File->Settings->Build, Execution, Deployment->CMake` then add `-DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH="C:/path/to/Qt/5.X/compiler/lib/cmake"` to the CMake options field.